# Настройка Git LFS на своем сервере

Tags: git

Имеется свой git-сервер, с доступом через ssh. В нем проект размером 25Gb. Установил LFS и пытался конвертировать проект с помощью утилиты [git-lfs-migrate](https://github.com/bozaro/git-lfs-migrate). Получаю ошибку:

> "[main] ERROR git.lfs.migrate.Main - LFS server: Invalid base URL"

Насколько я понял, утилита нуждается в настроенном `Git LFS API` поверх `http` или `https`.

Может быть у кого-то имеется опыт перевода большого git-репозитария на Git LFS? (имеется в виду на собственном git-сервере, а не github и аналоги). Буду признателен за ссылку на подробную инструкцию.

Comment: Опыта нет. А какое ПО установлено на сервере? Поддерживает ли оно LFS?

Comment: Операционка Centos 7, установлен git версии 2.12.0

Comment: Тут представлен список серверов, которые поддерживают LFS: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations

Comment: *Invalid base URL* — видимо, вы некорректно указали url хранилища (и в вопросе вы его не приводите). смотрите по приведённой вами же ссылке — там есть подсказка «Supported Git url formats:»